# How can I have an observable call another one based on the result?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

The situation:

I have an http request, that, once I get it I need to make another request. However, the second request that I make depends on the result of the first one. As in, my first request returns either pass or fail, and if it returns pass I want to call apiPass, and if it fails I want to instead return a different Observable.

I know if I had just one call to call after the first, I could use something like mergemap and write something like

```
return this.http.post<{id:string, resPass:boolean}>(this.urlFirst, bodyObject)
    .pipe(mergeMap(this.http.get<any>(this.passUrl)));
```

But my situation is different - I want to use resPass to know if I should indeed call the pass Api, or if I should instead do the fail logic (which should also return an Observable, just a different one). How can I, without subscribing unnecessarily, map to one Observable (`http.get(this.passUrl)`) if the first call param passes, and a different one (`otherObservable`) if the param fails?

In both instances my first call should return `http code 200` , so it is not a matter of an http failure either.

Any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, I would try something along these lines

```
return this.http.post<{id:string, resPass:boolean}>(this.urlFirst, bodyObject)
 .pipe(
     // concatMap is the preferred operator for typical http operations, see below for more details
     concatMap(({id:string, resPass:boolean}) => resPass ? 
                       this.http.get<any>(this.passUrl) : 
                       otherObservable)
 );
```

It is usually preferable to use `concatMap` operator when dealing with http async requests, since such operator ensures that we receive the response from http before proceeding with other observable-related async operations, such in this case where we have potentially to make another http call after the first one has returned.

Within `concatMap` we define the structure of the value expected as return from the first call using destructuring (i.e. with this form `({id:string, resPass:boolean})`) and then, depending from the value of `ressPass` we either perform the second http call or we return `otherObservable`, assuming that this has been defined somewhere before.

You may get some inspiration about typical patterns of use of rxjs with http [looking at this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Comment: The use of concatMap, exhaustMap, switchMap and mergeMap depends on the type of http request you're doing. For a get like that, depending on the application behind, a switchMap is probably better.

Comment: @Jean-Xavier Raynaud I agree with you, IT  DEPENDS. At the same time my comment about `concatMap` as the usually right operator for http calls derives from my experience and from a comment of Ben LEsh, the main contributor of rxjs, which you can listen at the beginning of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dsku0F4lU3A&list=PLJBWPTwg7fuNKFg5BRXKTvDrEi-45YzSE&index=1&t=46s). The preference for `concatMap` is stronger with POST calls, since it ensures you receive the response from each call before doing anything, which helps avoiding multiple POST in fly at the same time.